# Understanding a modified variant of Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, primes

I came across this algorithm on a coding site (There was no author's information) which counts all prime numbers less than a given limit. It looks very similar to SoE algorithm but it is different in the way it counts the primes:

```
public int countPrimes(int n) {
    if (n < 3) return 0;
    boolean[] s = new boolean[n];
    int c = n / 2;
    for (int i = 3; i < Math.sqrt(n); i += 2) {
        if (s[i]) continue;
        for (int j = i * i; j < n; j += 2 * i) {
            if (!s[j]) {
                c--;
                s[j] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

It sets the initial count to half the limit then decrement it, but I can not seem to understand why does this work. Can anyone please explain?

Comment: Only odd numbers are viable candidates for being primes, and there are `n/2` of them.

Comment: explanation is a big and vast question, maybe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes can help you more than SO, this guy does a pretty good job at explaining https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lj_SzTGr-G4

Comment: number of primes + number of composites == number of all the numbers in the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the boolean array **s** represents SoE.

The first loop iterates odd numbers from 3 to **sqrt(n)** (Because all even except 2 is not prime).
At the 6th line, If **i** is already in the **s**, continue to next odd number. If not, add all multiple of **i** that is less or equal to **n** to **s** in the second loop.

In addition, the second loop starts from **i*i** because all multiple of **i** smaller than **i*i** are already checked in prior loops.

Comment: Does it not matter if n is even or odd considering that `n/2` is floored? Second, `n/2` being the count of odd numbers less than n, then doesn't it mean that prime 2 is excluded from the count?

Comment: 1. n/2 is automatically floored (because **c** is integer) //
2. No, **floor(n/2)** means number of odd numbers less than n. but 1 is not a prime, thus we can replace 1 to 2.

Answer (score 1):

The count is initialized to n/2 because all even numbers (except 2) are not primes.
And then the loop below can start checking from multiples of 3.
If a new non-prime is found (!s[j]), the count of primes (c) is decreased.